# Jquery validation shows the error message in wrong place

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I used Jquery validation to form validation. The form has dynamic fields. I need to show the error message in the respective field. For example, I have two fields are test1 and test2. The test2 field having the error message so that message supposed to show it only but that message was shown to the test1 field.The error message showing in the wrong place.

Here, My form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="submit-requirements-form" action="/organizations" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">  
  <input name="submit_requirements[sites][sample_page_url][]" id="submit_requirements_sites_sample_page_url_1" placeholder="http://www.ebay.com/sch/DSLR-Cameras/31388/bn_732/i.html" class="sample_page_url url_fields error" type="text">
   /-- Here you can see the error message. This is wrong and it should come to second input --/
  <label id="submit_requirements_sites_sample_page_url_1-error" class="error" for="submit_requirements_sites_sample_page_url_1">Crawling of this site is not feasible.</label>

  <input name="submit_requirements[sites][sample_page_url][]" id="submit_requirements_sites_sample_page_url_2" placeholder="http://www.ebay.com/sch/DSLR-Cameras/31388/bn_732/i.html" class="sample_page_url url_fields" type="text">
</form>
```

My Jquery code

```
$("#submit-requirements-form").validate();

$('input.url_fields').each(function() {
   $(this).rules('add', {
     url2: true,
     remote: {
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/sites/check_feasibility',
       dataType: 'json',
       dataFilter: function(resp) {
         console.log(resp);
         resp = JSON.parse(resp);
         return resp.status === 'feasible';
      }
    },
   messages: {
     url2: 'Please enter the URL of a page from where you would like to extract data.',
     remote: 'Crawling of this site is not feasible.'
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: They have the same name. Perhaps that is the issue

Comment: You cannot use the same `name` more than once.  The `name` is how the plugin keeps track of inputs so you'll need to make sure it's unique on each field.

Answer (score 0):

Use error Placement in jquery validation

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
   if (element.attr("name") == "element_name") {
      error.insertAfter('#element_div_id');
   }
   else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: In this case the names are the same

Comment: name might be same because he might need to store values in the array

Comment: if it is fixed that only 2 input are there we can give index too. i.e. in first input put 0 in the [0] and in the next one [1]